# Xcode : controlling the iAd

Tags: xcode, iad

is it possible to control the iAd in my application after it's launched ?
for example: if I have an app for my blog and it supports iAd, and whenever I have an important news I wanna display it in the iAd . 
So is it possible to remotely change the iAd to display the add I want at anytime I want..??

thank u..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't change the content of the iAd banner. This would allow you, for example, to charge Apple for iAds while displaying your own messages in the iAd banners.

So you can display your message in another view.